# iOS User steps count

Tags: ios, objective-c, accelerometer

I am working on the iPhone app in **Objective-C** in which I count steps of user by using **CMAccelerometerData**.

It works fine when app is running in background ,

But when I kill my app (double-clicking the Home button and then swiping app away) then I can not get the steps count.

The feature of app is that fetch steps count if my app is in kill state (double-clicking the Home button and then swiping app away) and I run it from icon.

Is there any way to get steps count if our app is killed (double-clicking the Home button and then swiping app away) ?

Here is the method to get steps

```
  - (void)startDetectionWithUpdateBlock:(void (^)(NSError *))callback
{

    if (self.motionManager.isAccelerometerActive) {
        return;
    }

    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:self.queue withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            if (callback) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    callback (error);
                });
            }
            return ;
        }


        CMAcceleration acceleration = accelerometerData.acceleration;

        CGFloat strength = 1.2f;

        BOOL isStep = NO;

        if (fabs(acceleration.x) > strength || fabs(acceleration.y) > strength || fabs(acceleration.z) > strength) {
            isStep = YES;
        }

        if (isStep) {
            if (callback) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    callback (nil);
                });
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

And through this way I **update steps count** :

```
[[SOLocationManager sharedInstance] start];

[[SOStepDetector sharedInstance] startDetectionWithUpdateBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
        return;
    } 

    self.actualCheckpoint.stepsCount ++;

    NSLog(@"Total Steps: %ld",(long)self.actualCheckpoint.stepsCount);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:SBCompetitionStepsCountDidChange object:self.actualCheckpoint];

}];
```

Comment: When you say 'kill my app' do you mean you're double-clicking the Home button and then swiping your app away or do you mean the app simply goes into the background state?

Comment: yes "double-clicking the Home button and then swiping app away"

Comment: i also edit my question

Comment: Why are you using accelerometer data? It is very inefficient in terms of power consumption. And, as you said, it doesn't work when the app is killed. Why don't you use HealthKit instead?

Comment: is HealthKit give data when app is killed?
any sample code or tutorial @FreeNickname

Comment: @hunaintariq, HealthKit is a build-in framework that aggregates health-related info from all apps in the system. The HealthKit storage is always on. And on new iPhones (starting from 5S) steps count is calculated in background automatically using the Mx co-processor. More info about HealthKit can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/).

Comment: @hunaintariq have you found solution for this

Answer (score 0):

you can catch the data in appDelegate's

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {}
```

Comment: read my question please, i want to get data after killing the app(double-clicking the Home button and then swiping app away) and run it again

Comment: @hunaintariq i mean you can cache the data before app terminates, so you can read it again next time you launch the app, even you force to quit the app, applicationWillTerminate will still get called.

Comment: i want to get latest data, if app is killed and user do steps i want that steps which user do while app is killed. i want that steps count

Comment: as i know no app can't still work after killed, so the only possible way to achieve your goal is to get the informations from apple health where the system counts the steps for you, official doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014707

Answer (score 0):

You can't access HealthKit data in the background when the device is locked, according to Apple:

> For security, the HealthKit store is encrypted when the device is locked. The HealthKit store can only be accessed by an authorized app. As a result, you may not be able to read data from the store when your app is launched in the background; however, apps can still write data to the store, even when the phone is locked. HealthKit temporarily caches the data and saves it to the encrypted store as soon as the phone is unlocked.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HealthKit_Framework/

You'll need to read the data on startup to 'catch up' from the last time your app was run.

Answer (score 0):

If the app is killed by the user by swiping up, rather than by simply putting the app into the background, it is no longer allows to execute any code until the user opens it again. However, there's no way to get direct access to the accelerometer if the app is completely killed.

There are ways to handle keeping the app open indefinitely if it goes into the background (not manually killed by the user). However, having the accelerometer powered up constantly would be a significant battery drain, and if all you want to do it track steps, you can simply use the HealthKit API. (If you need your app to work on old devices, you will have to resort to background processing.)

### HealthKit

As an Apple OS-level API, HealthKit is always working and (if the user's device supports it and the user hasn't disabled it) is constantly tracking steps in the background, using Apple's accurate, battery efficient algorithm (it uses the device's motion coprocessor).

All you need to do is integrate your app with HealthKit such that it can read the device's Steps metric. Take a look at [this objective-C tutorial](http://jademind.com/blog/posts/healthkit-api-tutorial/).